# Is it okay to use real-world literary figures?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, history, mythology, archaeology

In my world's lore and history, there a mythical figures and heroes in it. My world is not Earth, but rather a different world (think ATLA or skyrim kind of different). I was wondering if I am able to use characters like Sinbad, Beowulf, or King Arthur, in my world's lore, but of course with some changes to their stories, like where they lived, their kingdoms, etc. Would it be okay to use them in a high fantasy setting that is not Earth, with several differences?

Edit: They are not the main plot to my story or anything, they are just background lore to the world's history and mythos.

Comment: This seems like a highly subjective question.

Comment: Yet it can be objectively answered.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the rules of your world, but it has to do with the rules of our world with respect to writing.

Comment: Wouldn't that be fanfiction? They exist (fanfiction.net for anime fanfictions), but I don't think you can monetize your work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://writing.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is your second question, out of 3, where you ask "Is it ok to X?". As a general guidance, "is it ok?" is a poor question everywhere on SO, because it calls for opinions.

Comment: @L.Dutch Law.SE has a category of "is X Legal" which would befit this.

Answer (score 5):

##### Yes, Indeed it's Not Okay and Sometimes it Is

The question you're asking has a fundamentally simple answer, which is **Never play with the matches of copyright around the gasoline spill that is a powerful copyright holder's legal team**.

Copyright is, worldwide, a kind of fuzzy concept of idea ownership. Various things can fall under copyright, like characters and stories as matters of specific text. Every year, as books fall out of copyright, literary characters enter the strange world of public domain. Copyright lengths vary as well as what can be done and what is forbidden and not all countries respect everyone else's ethics on the matter --- e.g., China and Russia.

The characters you mention specifically predate the concept of copyright entirely, so ***as originally conceived*** they can never have been protected by copyright which means you can use them. Any way you want.

Now the question becomes, which Beowulf or which Thor are you using in your own world? If you're using the Old English Beowulf, then you'd be fine. If you're using Thor as he exists in the MCU, then you're stepping on some greedy lawyer's copyright landmine.

Newer literary figures like Harry Potter and Bilbo Baggins present different problems. Tolkien Estate has long been famed for loosing the great dragons of the North on anyone who infringes on their copyright *claims*. JKR has been much more lenient and welcoming of the use of her invented world and characters by fan fiction writers.

**Conclusion**: The safest bet is to pick literary characters that are out of copyright in the country you are writing in. A 1500 year old semi-legendary King of the Britons is fair game. Monty Python's King Arthur, not so much!

---

Note that I put the word "claims" in italics --- as I understand it, TolkEst *claims* that the word "hobbit" is either a trademark or a matter of copyright. (Six of one, half dozen of the other, because Lawyers are involved either way.) The problem is, they can't really copyright the word, because the word predated Tolkien's use of it. A hobbit is apparently some kind of English countryside sprite or nature spirit; and you'd be within rights to use the word that way.

However, Tolkien Estate is rich while you are not, and they have an army of powerful lawyers while you do not. Guess whose head the gavel of justice is likely to fall upon!

Answer (score 2):

### Probably, but be careful

Legally, it should be fine, so long as the characters you're using are from works whose copyright has expired. I believe that is true for the specific characters you mention (but I'm not sure who "Nicholas Flamel" is).

As far as worldbuilding, you've got to consider what you hope to accomplish by using these figures. When your readers see these names, they will immediately import all the things they know about those characters from other works. If your story then goes on to change any of those details, it risks upsetting the reader or even having them reject it. This can happen because the reader knows you didn't invent these characters and thus you have no claim to authorial control.

You're playing with fire when you borrow something that you didn't create and about which your audience may have strong feelings.

Comment: Nicholas Flamel was a 14th/15th century scribe and book seller. His reputation as an alchemist (as we see in the Wizarding World) appears to have arisen in the 17th century.

Answer (score 2):

**It Mostly Depends on your Story's Gimmick**

The idea you are proposing sounds a lot like an "All the myths are true" kind of story. This would be similar to the Percy Jackson books. In those, all the fictional characters of Greek mythology are real to some extent and are living in a hidden unseen reality.

That could be one way to write your story. The main character initially thinks all these characters are fictional and then learns "Oh, there's a whole secret magic society/world where all these people are alive and kicking."

Your method sounds more like taking a bunch of previously existing lore and using it to make a new world. This has been done many times before, especially with things like fairy tales. In the Land of Stories book series, for example, there is a world where all famous fairytale characters such as Cinderella, Goldilocks, and so on are all real people with real kingdoms. It's a relatively common trope.

You could also have fully original characters but just give them the names of famous and well-known characters to simply evoke their story. The main character might be a captain named Odysseus, so if you know how that myth goes you probably realize he's about to get stranded at sea for a long time.

The best way to take multiple unique stories and tie them together into one cohesive narrative is to do the following.

1-Research the source material so you know you're at least being faithful to the original. If it's particularly relevant to the story and you have the patience, read the full book. If not, just make sure you know the character.

2-Figure out how that would fit into your own world. If your world's not the earth, it doesn't make sense for Odysseus to be here because Greece wouldn't exist, so why not make a kingdom that is similar to Greece in culture but with your own unique elements. For example, the Greek gods really exist in this fake Greece, and they are incredibly powerful enemies.

3-Lastly, have fun with it. Feel free to embellish, take away details, or add details wherever necessary to enhance the story. If the point of the tale is to have King Arthur, Beowulf, and Sinbad all be friends, maybe have them all be brought together by some horrible monster that threatens all their kingdoms. The villain or entity could be an original addition or it could be a reference to another work. Maybe reference H.P. Lovecraft and have the villain be Cthulu. That's one option.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly You  say '*My world is not Earth, but rather a different world.*' without going into any specifics about *how* it actually differs from Earth. So it's kind of hard to give a precise answer.

You can have characters with different names who have similar if not identicle adventures to famous figures from fiction or real life but you can't just use the names without creating some reason for all those characters being where they are instead of where they were supposed to be. Well at least not easily. (Why is King Arthur riding a dinosaur through the deserts of Africa?)

So if you want great characters from literature and real world historical figures in your adventure then it's really far easier to write a story set in the  **'Alternate history/Earth SF & Fantasy genre**. You just change the Earth *slightly* and at some point briefly enunciate what those changes are so that the reader has an explanation for why the characters are facing whatever challenges you've given them. Some small but critical feature of the World's climate, geography or history etc that splits your Earth off on a tangent from the real one.

(Thanks to whoever cleaned this answer up BTW)

Answer (score 0):

1. what roles did this character play in your story.
2. a short and longterm impact of their doings or rather the influence they have on the story.

those are what i think you could consider in your story.

in my opinion, if your world is somehow related to earth, maybe it will be weird, but "justified" whatever that is.

if it didn't, then i think it could make readers feel uncanny about the story. especially with all with all of the fantasy element around them. but if **you did** you could turn this as a way of "literature fanfic" if you wanted so. even in our world cross over is common to write.

anyway, this question i think should've been asked to writing stack exchange, instead of this one. and I'm afraid your question would be close already.